# Can't change Properties in listView java file

Tags: android, listview, searchview

I have try tutorial from here, it's working great but i want to make just one text in the `listView`.

Here's this link
    http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html

Can anyone help me? I have modified this code:

```
package com.as400samplecode;

public class Country {

 private String code = "";


 public Country(String code) {
  super();
  this.code = code;

 }

 public String getCode() {
  return code;
 }
 public void setCode(String code) {
  this.code = code;
 }

}
```

but if I run it, It's still work but, its be a same text from the top to the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExpandableListView Child Row Layout - child_row.xml
use only one textview insted of three in the xml which i have mentioned

Comment: its my pleasure bro :-)

Comment: if you got your answer then please accept it so that others can take help from it :-)

Comment: Can u help me answer my new question sir?I really need it.